# "Unable to create version backup"

Tags: blend-files

[image: Here is a screen capture of the error]

It happens fairly often when I save. Incrementing the file name fixes it. It also doesn't stop the file itself from saving, as far as I can tell.

What causes this to happen? I do save my iterations via Google Drive, could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: it seems [google drive renames files that contain numbers](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/drive/rename/drive/dGBuj5EnncU) ,my guess is blender tries to check the existence of the backup and fails to find the file, hence that error.

Answer (score 2):

Google Drive is very likely the reason in this case, as it has to lock access to the file while syncing it with the Cloud. But it can also happen (and does happen) to me when a file is located on the server, and the server is creating Shadow Copies of it. In our company the server is setup this way, every hour changed files will be backed up, so the likeliness of saving over just that one blend file which is currently being backed up is not that small.

What I noticed then is that on the Server a file with an **'@'** at the end will be left behind. I have to manually delete it, before I can save my blend file again, if not Blender will continue to complain about it being there.

Comment: I've also had this happen with background backup services other than Google Drive. Fix is to delete the @ file, pause the backup, and save again.

Answer (score 1):

When google drive is syncing a file, it quickly locks the folder and this gives Blender issues when saving. Just wait a couple of seconds until the file is finished uploading or save and delete the file with the `@` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is in the attached image (File saved with @) looks like when saving, an unsupported character is in the file name (@) I don't know though if saving to Google Drive is causing this issue.

Comment: I tend not to use external images at all, actually. In any case, it's more of a minor annoyance I've been trying to work out for a few weeks now. Incrementing my file names often makes automated backups somewhat redundant anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not very difficult. All you have to do is open two blender windows, then press you on the mesh that you want from the project (ctrl + c) in the first window and in the second window, create a new project and press (ctrl + v).